# Laravel 4.2 project not working after uploading - public folder not visible in browser

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4

I've created a laravel project which is working fine on localhost and my hosting server but when I upload it on my client's server it just doesn't work (he's using bluehost).

When I open the URL which is pointing to **/public** folder, it should display the homepage. Instead it is showing the listing of all files and folders (except **public** folder).

When I try to open **myurl.com/public** or **myurl.com/public/index.php** in browser, it gives following error:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /license/public/ on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I can see **public** folder via FTP and I've changed permissions **for /app/storage** to **777**

Here is my **public/.htaccess**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've checked my **/public/error_log**, its showing following error:

```
[21-Aug-2015 09:06:01] PHP Fatal error:  require() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '__DIR__/../bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home6/parentv3/public_html/eldercareapp/license/public/index.php on line 21
```

Any help?

Comment: It may feel stupid but did you do `composer install`

Comment: Yes did that ofcourse

Comment: What is PHP version on the server?

Comment: @AdityaGiri I'm surprised why I didn't think of it. Just checked the PHP version on server and its 5.2.17. That is the reason of all this mess. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade PHP on this server? Its BlueHost, can this be done via cPanel or I'll have to contact the hosting company's support?

Comment: It is better to contact company to do this. As far what I am concerned, you must use some service like Fortrabbit or Laravel Forge. And if you are really a SaaS based person, you should use AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I had contacted client's hosting company and asked them to upgrade PHP version. They took a couple of days and upgraded PHP to 5.5.

But the problem was still there even after updating PHP. I wasn't able to access **/public** folder so the problem was somewhere else. After some searching and trying I've found a solution.

The problem was actually in my **/public/.htaccess** file. I've added just one line in my **.htaccess** and it solved the problem: `Options +FollowSymLinks`

My updated **.htaccess** in **/public** now looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Well the problem is with your PHP version. If you see your PHP Version, you might get what is wrong with your application. You must use version greater than PHP 5.5

Answer (score 0):

Changing permissions to 777 is a terrible idea because it will be vulnerable, instead try with `sudo chmod -R 775 project/` where project is the name of your project's folder, then do the next `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER project/` to make the project's folder be owned by your user, finally, if you haven't done it, cd into the project's folder and  run `composer install`

Comment: Tried 'sudo chmod -R 777 project_name/' and also did 'composer install' already. Still no luch.. :(

Comment: Where did you placed your project's folder? Maybe the apache server is not serving the route where it's stored

Comment: The problem was with my clients hosting company, they are running PHP version 5.2. I've contacted them to upgrade php version.

Comment: Oh I see, I'm glad that everything is fine now :)